# Prove inequality $a^3b^3+2b^3c^3+3a^3c^3\le 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

For $a^3+b^3+c^3=0$. Prove that $a^3b^3+2b^3c^3+3a^3c^3\le 0$

---

i think from $a^3+b^3+c^3=0$ we have one of the three numbers is zero, the other two are opposites.Suppose $a;b$ opposites and $c=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make:

$$a^3b^3+2b^3c^3+3a^3c^3=b^3(a^3+2c^3)+3a^3c^3$$

but, $a^3+2c^3=c^3-b^3$, so

$$b^3(c^3-b^3)+3a^3c^3=-b^6+c^3(b^3+3a^3)$$

but, $b^3+3a^3=-2b^3-3c^3$, so

$$-b^6+c^3(-2b^3-3c^3)=-[(b^3+c^3)^2+2c^6]\le 0$$

Comment: How did you get the last equality?

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand: if you expand the square on the RHS, the middle term is $-2b^3c^3$, not $-2a^3c^3$. What am I missing?

Comment: @Nick: You are right. There were a little mistake. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @Arnaldo: OK - that looks correct now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To simplify the notation, replace $\,a^3 \mapsto a, \,b^3 \mapsto b, \,c^3 \mapsto c\,$ so the problem becomes:

> for $a+b+c=0\,$, prove that $\,ab+2bc+3ac\le 0$

Then, given that $b+c=-a\,$ and $a+b = -c\,$:

$$
ab+2bc+3ac = (ab+ac)+2(bc+ac)=a(b+c)+2c(a+b)=-a^2 - 2c^2 \le 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$a^3b^3+2b^3c^3+3a^3c^3=a^3b^3-(a^3+b^3)(3a^3+2b^3)=$$
$$=-(3a^6+4a^3b^3+2b^6)=-a^6-2(a^3+b^3)^2\leq0.$$

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, let $a^3=x,b^3=y,c^3=z$. Then: $x+y+z=0\Rightarrow x=-(y+z).$

$$xy+2yz+3xz=$$
$$-y(y+z)+2yz-3z(y+z)=$$
$$-y^2-2yz-3z^2=$$
$$-(y+z)^2-2z^2\le0.$$